# Create a virtual column and index to optimize a filter for an array in a JSON column

Tags: json, sql-server, indexing, query-optimization, virtual-column

Here is the microsoft document for how to optimize a json column with out using OpenJson and only using Json_Value:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/index-json-data?view=sql-server-ver15

My issue is that I have a JSON column that contains an array where I am trying to grab all keys called Test_ID from each element in the array to compare with a joined statements testId and, while it works, its relatively slow. Takes about 9 seconds for 400 rows. I am trying to speed this up exponentially and it seems the only way to do so is through the indexing mentioned in that article but I can not seem to figure out how to do it for an array.

My JSON is similar to this: `'{"Property":{"Label":"0"},"Tests":[{"Test_ID":"GUID_HERE","Type":{"Label":" "},"Name":{"Label":" "},"Value":null,{"Test_ID":"GUID_HERE","Type":{"Label":" "},"Name":{"Label":" "},"Value":" "}]}'`

Here is my scrubbed query

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.W_ID, 
       'Proc' ProcHeaderName, p.ProcNumber ProcValue, 
       'Class' ClassHeaderName, p.Class ClassValue 
INTO #Procs
FROM proc p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT wt.W_ID, wt.TestId 
    from TestValue wt where wt.IsDeleted = 0) as wtRow on wtRow.W_ID in (SELECT ID FROM #tmp) 
LEFT JOIN TableNameHere c on c.IsDeleted = 0 and c.col_ID in (SELECT col_ID FROM tmp)
WHERE p.IsDeleted = 0 and [dbo].[GetTestIdJson](c.Json, wtRow.TestId) = wtRow.TestId
    AND p.ProcNumber + ',' + p.RNumber = JSON_VALUE(c.Json,'$.Property.Label') + ',' + JSON_VALUE(c.Json,'$.Property.Label')
GROUP BY wtRow.W_ID, p.ProcNumber, p.Class
```

Comment: For performance related questions we need to see your execution plan.

Comment: Consider that scalar function dbo.GetTestIdJson() has to be invoked for every row in the joined data set and likely won't appear with real costs in any plan estimates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

… indexed view … [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a61d428c4ca49fb1f339f920b4ed1478)

```
create table dbo.a (id int primary key, json nvarchar(max));   
insert into dbo.a values(1, '{"Property":{"Label":"0"},"Tests":[{"Test_ID":"GUID_HERE1","Type":{"Label":" "},"Name":{"Label":" "},"Value":null},{"Test_ID":"GUID_HERE2","Type":{"Label":" "},"Name":{"Label":" "},"Value":" "}]}');
insert into dbo.a values(2, '{"Property":{"Label":"0"},"Tests":[{"Test_ID":"GUID_HERE21","Type":{"Label":" "},"Name":{"Label":" "},"Value":null},{"Test_ID":"GUID_HERE22","Type":{"Label":" "},"Name":{"Label":" "},"Value":" "}]}');
GO
--numbers table
create table dbo.n(n int primary key);
insert into dbo.n values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10); --assume max 11 elements in Tests[]
GO
create view dbo.v
with schemabinding
as
select a.id, n.n, json_value(a.json, concat('$.Tests[', n.n,'].Test_ID')) as Test_Id
from dbo.a as a
cross join dbo.n as n
where json_value(a.json, concat('$.Tests[', n.n,'].Test_ID')) is not null;
GO
create unique clustered index vuidx on dbo.v(id,n);
create index idTestId on dbo.v(Test_Id);
GO
select * from dbo.v
GO
set statistics xml on;
select *
from dbo.v with(noexpand)
where Test_Id = 'GUID_HERE2';
GO
drop view if exists dbo.v;
GO
drop table if exists dbo.n;
GO
drop table if exists dbo.a;
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you! Will note that I had to add COUNT_BIG(*) as countN to the select statement or it errored out when trying to add the clustered index